# How to style an element onDragOver in Material-UI?

Tags: css, material-ui, dom-events

To change the backgroundColor on hover, I can use `sx={{"&:hover":{backgroundColor:"yellow"}}`

How can I change the backgroundColor on dragover? `sx={{"&:dragOver":{backgroundColor:"yellow"}}` doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pseudo class in CSS like `:dragOver`. To style element on `dragOver` you will have to add and remove class on `dragEnter` and `dragLeave` event respectively. Roughly steps are:- First create css class with styles you want.
Then add the class to the element on `dragEnter` event and remove it on `dragLeave` event.